# Tool for detecting copy/pasted code in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a SQL Server 2005 system with a lot of copy-pasted code, lots of repeated calculations instead of functions, many stored procedures that differ only very slightly instead of being parameterized.  Also lots of SSIS packages that are very similar.

Moving forward, I'd like to be able to to detect this type of "code smell".  There's lots of tools around for this, but I haven't found anything for SQL.

Any ideas on products to use, or best practices to apply regarding copy/pasted code in TSQL?

Many thanks...

EDIT:
Thanks for all the feedback.  I poked around with a couple of them, but the one that looks most straightforward and easy to use appears to be Atomiq.  I had to exported all my objects to .sql files, then had to use a batch file to rename all the files with extension .sql to .cs because it doesn't use .sql.  However, I've already gotten some good information on major problems with our code.

Comment: be careful at what you change.  If you are truly working on a system built by a hack you won't break anything.  However, if the system was done by someone really good, then you could be breaking a lot of good query plans!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several for that purpose:

- [Atomiq](http://getatomiq.com/) - commercial
- [Black Duck Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Duck_Software) - commercial (software analyzing suite)
- [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/) - commercial (Ada, C, C++, C#, Java, COBOL, Fortran, Python, VB.net, VB6, PHP4/5, PLSQL, SQL2011, XML, many others)
- [ConQAT](http://conqat.cs.tum.edu/index.php/ConQAT) (Open Source, supports: ABAP, ADA, Cobol, C/C++, C#, Java, PL/I, PL/SQL, Python, Text, Transact SQL, Visual Basic, XML)
- [Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/index.html) (software)

Answer (score 4):

You could try to run [Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/features.html). It is a tool which supports many languages (including SQL)

Answer (score 1):

A prepackaged tool is probably going to be the fastest/easiest way to get there, but a way to get there with maximum hacker points and maximum fun would be to run a [Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) against the stored procedure code in the database, which can easily be accessed using:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as ProcName, 
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) as ProcCode
FROM sys.procedures
```

[Here is one example](http://blog.sendreallybigfiles.com/2009/06/improved-t-sql-levenshtein-distance.html) of someone implementing the algorithm in T-SQL.

Of course, you also need to iterate through all the procs and compare them one-to-one covering every combination, and then cluster the results.

I might actually try this myself, just for kicks!